# поиск в строке регулярного выражения с подстрокой c++

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, строки

есть строка:

```
std::string init;
std::getline(std::cin,init);
```

как выполнить поиск подстроки, в которой будет содержаться нечто, соответствующее регулярному выражению, а затем еще какая-то подстрока?

например, нечто соответствующее такому регулярному выражению: "\s\d+\s", а сразу после подстрока: "пример."

необходимо определить местоположение(номер первого/последнего символа) такого вхождения

Comment: Вкратце, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Comment: Если ответ ниже вас устраивает, отметьте его как верное решение. Если нет, объясните, что вам нужно: добавьте примерную строку и желаемый результат в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартная библиотека с++ начиная с С++11 предоставляет средства для работы с регулярными выражениями. (Заголовочный файл: `regex`)

---

Пример использования.

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout
#include <regex>    // regex tools
#include <string>   // std::string

int main()
{
  std::string str{ "To be, or not to be, that is the question..." }; // исходная строка
  std::regex rex{ "(\\S+)" }; // регулярное выражение
  std::sregex_iterator beg{ str.cbegin(), str.cend(), rex }; // итератор
  // на начало последовательности найденных совпадений
  std::sregex_iterator end{};  // 'нулевой' итератор

  for (auto i = beg; i != end; ++i)
  { // проходим по всем совпадениям: выводим значения (*1),
    // их индексы относительно начала исходной строки
    // и длину совпадаемой строки
      std::cout << i->str() << "(" << i->position() << ") ["
          << i->length() << "]\n";
  }
}
```

**(*1)** - необходимо учесть что метод `str` возвращает новый объект `std::string`

И чтобы узнать индекс последнего символа вхождения можно провести нехитрые вычисления

`auto last_index = i->position() + i->length() /* - 1 при надобности*/;`